# How do I disable the manual WiFi hardware switch?

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch

My laptop has a manual networking hardware switch on it. It hasn't caused me many issues until I switched to Ubuntu. Now, it randomly shuts itself off, requiring me to turn the networking switch off and on to fix it. How would I manually disable it so it does nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable a hardware switch using your operating system.

A hardware switch physically disables and enables whatever component the switch is designed to control.

You cannot use software to enable a component that has been disabled by a hardware switch.

If you want to use software to enable and disable this hardware you will need to always keep the hardware switch on the "On" position.

Comment: That sucks. Oh well.